# How to find why query was blocked?

Tags: sql-server

I have some query, that run from client and have 5 sec timeout.
In most cases query work faster then 1 second, but sometimes it got timeout after 5 sec and the query execution does not start.
I added a message at the beginning of the procedure that it is running, but even that is not saved in the database.
I ran a profiler trace and this is what it shows [image]
I also turned on the blocked process report with paramert 4 sec, but i don`t see any blocking processes in that time (17:29-17:30).
[image]
How to investigate this problem?

Comment: Temporarily remove the timeout, see how long a "long" execution takes to fully run and investigate that (through `sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks` and/or query plans). The blocked process report does not fully cover all things that can cause query execution to stall.

Comment: Also note that the blocked process threshold is going to be rather ineffective in your scenario. This is because the detector only runs every 5 seconds, regardless of the value of this setting. To produce a report, it would therefore have to be lucky enough to notice your blocked query running for 4+ seconds at the time it wakes up, which is improbable.